# Configure MongoDB with Nutch2.3, some error about indexerJob?

Tags: mongodb, nutch

I had successfully configure MongoDB(5.3.1) and Nutch(2.3), when I run the command "./bin/nutch index -all" some errors printed after inject/generate/fetch/parse/updatedb commands work,the error details like:

```
SolrIndexerJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_local140530148_0001
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:154)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:176)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:211)
```

I had configure the file in $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml
details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all the others steps was running, it would be not a problem with mongodb but with solr (your nutch-site.xml suggests that you wanted index your data in solr). As far that i remember, when i used solr, i precised the core name, it would be something like that :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, you mean, I have to create my own new core for solr, and then edit the configuration relative. Did you use the mid-extension "MongoDB-Connector" to sychronized the data you crawler from seed.txt using nutch?

Comment: No, i used HBase to store my crawl db. To indexing my data, i used Solr during some days and i switched to elastic.  Yes you can try this, i didn't touch to Solr since some months but i remember that i precised the core. Maybe it's not the problem here, but it's fast to verify. :)